# jQuery-File-Upload doesn't return $_FILES

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm using blueimp's jQuery File Upload to upload files and I'd like to write my own handler, however, it's not uploading files for some reason. I'm using CodeIgniter as framework.

I want to check if the files are uploaded, however $_FILES (console.log( data.result );) gives [] instead of the cached file. I'm working on a localhost environment.

My html

```
<form action="{{ base_url() }}ajax/update_client_status" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group inline m-b-none">
        <input type="file" data-type="process" class="filestyle" multiple="false" data-icon="false" data-classButton="btn btn-default" data-classInput="form-control v-middle inline input-s-lg" data-buttonText="Kies Excel" <!--accept=".csv, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"-->                        
    </div>
    <div id="progress" class="pull-right animated" style="display:none;">
        <small class="text-muted inline m-r-sm"><em></em></small>
        <div class="progress progress-sm progress-s-sm m-t-sm m-b-none inline">
            <div class="progress-bar bg-success"></div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</form>
```

The js

```
$(function(){   

    $('input:file[data-type=process]')
        .fileupload({
            add: function (e, data) { 
                if (data.autoUpload || (data.autoUpload !== false && $(this).fileupload('option', 'autoUpload'))) {
                    $('#progress')
                        .show()
                        .addClass('fadeIn')
                        .find('em').text('Uploaden');
                    data.process().done(function () {
                        data.submit();
                    });
                }
            },
            progress: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress .progress-bar').css( 'width', progress + '%');
            },
            done: function (e, data) {
                console.log( data.result );
            }
        });

});
```

And finally the CI controler

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Ajax extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function _remap( $method )
{
    if( !$this->input->is_ajax_request() ) {
        show_404(); // redirect to the 404 if ajax wasn't used for this request
    } else {
        $this->$method(); // continue the method
    }
}

public function update_client_status()
{
    $response = $_FILES;
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output( json_encode( $response ) );
}
}
```